# excel return the value of a cell based on two other values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What I'm trying to do is a little complex but I think it's doable in Excel.

I have two worksheets in a workbook on sheet one I have this...

```
| Code1 | Code2 | Code3 | Code4 |
|  BA1  | xxxxx | xxxxx |       |
|  BA2  | xxxxx | xxxxx |       |
|  BA3  | xxxxx | xxxxx |       |
```

And on the second sheet...

```
| CodeA | CodeB | CodeC | CodeD |
|  BA1  |   1   |  date | text  |
|  BA3  |   1   |  date | text  |
|  BA1  |   2   |  date | text  |
|  BA2  |   1   |  date | text  |
|  BA1  |   3   |  date | text  |
|  BA3  |   2   |  date | text  |
|  BA2  |   2   |  date | text  |
```

What I want to do is lookup Code1 on sheet one and find it in the second sheet in CodeA then find the highest CodeB for CodeA and then concatenate CodeC and CodeD and place them on Sheet one in Code4.

I hope that makes sense, Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand. Does this look correct?

[image]

Sorry for the swedish formulas but it's an array formula that you add with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

The formula in english is:

```
{=MAX(IF(Data=A2,CodeB;-1))}
```

And the named range Data is Column H and I, and CodeB is Column I.
If it does not find the value it returns `-1`

Sorry noticed now that I only did half of the job.

Make another named range called Table that spans column I to K (Code B -> Code D).

And in column code3 add this formula:

```
=Vlookup(B2,Table,2,false)
```

And in code4:

```
=Vlookup(B2,Table,3,false)
```

And you should get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should find the results you are looking for.

This is an array formula so you will need to press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER once you have entered it into the formula bar, this will have to done for every formula you add to the column.

As it is an array formula I have only written it to reference rows 1 to 18, you will need to update all references to include you last row.

Columns titled CODE1(to 4) are on the first sheet (Sheet 1)

Columns titled CODEA(to D) are on the Second sheet (Sheet 2)

```
=CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(A2,MAX(IF(Sheet2!A:A=A2,Sheet2!B:B,-1))), CHOOSE({1,2},Sheet2!A1:A18 & Sheet2!B1:B18, Sheet2!C1:C18 ),2,0)," ",VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(A2,MAX(IF(Sheet2!A:A=A2,Sheet2!B:B,-1))), CHOOSE({1,2},Sheet2!A1:A18 & Sheet2!B1:B18, Sheet2!D1:D18 ),2,0))
```

If you do not require a space between the dates, just remove " ", from the middle of the formula.

Comment: This works great, I just had to insert a TEXT formula to get the correct date format instead of numbers. Thanks!